# Auth::attempt() laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

please Help me, im  new in laravel 5.2
i manually code my login page in laravel.

when i enter my email address correctly in my login page even my password is null or incorrect it return true.

here is my code

userController.php
public function postSignIn(Request $request){

```
    $user = array(
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
    );

        if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
            return redirect() -> route('dashboard');

        }
      return redirect()->back();

}
```

}

please help me. thank you so much.

Comment: if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Login failed.');
        }

Comment: The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in your database table. So, in the example above, the user will be retrieved by the value of the email column. If the user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the hashed password value passed to the method via the array. If the two hashed passwords match an authenticated session will be started for the user.

The attempt method will return true if authentication was successful. Otherwise, false will be returned.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Hello @t9toqwerty thank you so much for the answer, i try the code that you suggested, but it give me same ouput, when i input email address correctly even my password is null it return true, but if my email is incorrect it return falls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dumping the data so you can see if the data being passed is correct.

```
$credentials =['email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>     $request['password'];

var_dump($credentials);
```

If you're sure the data is correct, then better to check the return of the attemp()

var_dump( Auth::attempt($credentials));

You can also check data validation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Also, it is good to check your database(users table) for null records.